# Total does not give the output expected

Tags: programming

Using the three matrices given below, I like to perform the operation stated in `Quiet[...]/.{Interderminate->0}`.

```
ClearAll[mat1, mat2, mat3];
mat1 = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 4 , 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
mat2 = {{1, 0}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 6}, {5, 4}, {6, 0}};
mat3 = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0}, {0, 0, 0.75, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

Quiet[Total[#, 1]/Total[Unitize[#], 1] &[(mat1/mat2[[All, -1]]) + mat3]]/.{Indeterminate->0}
```

This `code` generates:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

while I expect this:

```
{y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6}= {0,0,1.29,0,2.88,0}
```

since by hand I get:

```
y1 = 0;
y2 = 0;
y3 = ((2/6) + 0.75 + (4/4) + 0.5)/2 = 1.29;
y4 = 0;
y5 = ((6/2) + 0.25 + (8/4) + 0.5)/2 = 2.88;
y6 = 0;
```

To my surprise, the same `code` works fine for another set of matrices:

```
m1 = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {5, 0, 1, 0, 0}};
m2 = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 1.5}, {3, 2}, {4, 0.5}, {5, 2}};
m3 = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1.38, 0, 0, 1.42, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0}, {1.93, 0, 1.65, 0, 0}};
Quiet[Total[#, 1]/Total[Unitize[#], 1] &[(m1/m2[[All, -1]]) + m3]] /. {Indeterminate -> 0}
```

This generates the desired output (checked by hand like above):

```
{4.57167, 0, 2.15, 5.42, 0}
```

Why do I have this conflicting results? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a way to make it work

```
Quiet[(Total[#, 1]/Total[Unitize[#], 1]) &[(mat1/mat2[[All, -1]]) + 
 mat3 /. {Indeterminate -> 0}]] /. {Indeterminate -> 0}
```

> {0, 0, 1.29167, 0, 2.875, 0}

So you need to apply     `Indeterminate -> 0` twice

this happens because:
In your first code

```
 mat1/mat2[[All, -1]] + mat3
```

returns

> {{Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 
>     Indeterminate, Indeterminate}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 3.25, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
>     2.5, 0}, {0, 0, 1.08333, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, 
>     0}, {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 
>     Indeterminate, Indeterminate}}

while the second

```
(m1/m2[[All, -1]]) + m3
```

returns

> {{0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {4.71333, 0., 0., 5.42, 0.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
>     0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {4.43, 0, 2.15, 0, 0}}

and that is way it works

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. I spent a lot of time before considering to post this question. Now I understand why I had the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 5):

You can instead use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) to force [`Indeterminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indeterminate) to be 0:

```
Block[{Indeterminate=0},
    Quiet[Total[#,1]/Total[Unitize[#],1]&[(mat1/mat2[[All,-1]])+mat3]]
]
```

> {0, 0, 1.29167, 0, 2.875, 0}

Comment: It is really neat. Thank you for this very efficient code to avoid repeated `Indeterminate->0`.